# Android display contacts of type custom

Tags: android, android-contacts

I have imported an sample of Contact List...Form this link... http://developer.android.com/training/contacts-provider/display-contact-badge.html
this is working fine with all functionality....
Now in list if i want to display only some of the contact...the where should i fire a query for that ..and how...
   if any one has work on it...please help me...
     Thanks in advance....

Comment: means u want some contact from all contacts r8 dear

Comment: k i will try see my ans dear

Comment: Sure ,Thanks...for reply...

Answer (score 3):

you can also modify this query dear

```
cntx.getContentResolver().query(Contacts.CONTENT_URI, CONTACTS_SUMMARY_PROJECTION, select,
                    null, Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + " COLLATE LOCALIZED ASC");
```

i maintain one contact wrapper so i have all contact in one array list with name and all info so now just make one more contact name list which you want to display just check with original and display only those which you want

```
package com.rightbackup.parsing;

    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.HashMap;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.database.Cursor;
    import android.graphics.Color;
    import android.os.AsyncTask;
    import android.provider.ContactsContract;
    import android.provider.ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone;
    import android.provider.ContactsContract.Contacts;
    import android.widget.ListView;

    import com.rightbackup.constants.Constant;
    import com.rightbackup.setcontent.ContactsAdapter;
    import com.rightbackup.wrapper.ContactsWrapper;
    import com.rightbackup.wrapper.DataController;

    public class ReadContacts extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{

        private ListView contactsList;

        private Context cntx;
        private Constant constants;

        static final String[] CONTACTS_SUMMARY_PROJECTION = new String[] {
            Contacts._ID, // 0
            Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME, // 1
            Contacts.STARRED, // 2
            Contacts.TIMES_CONTACTED, // 3
            Contacts.CONTACT_PRESENCE, // 4
            Contacts.PHOTO_ID, // 5
            Contacts.LOOKUP_KEY, // 6
            Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER, // 7
        };

        private long contactId;
        private String display_name;
        private String phoneNumber;

        private ArrayList<ContactsWrapper>contactWrap = new ArrayList<ContactsWrapper>();
        private HashMap<Long, ArrayList<ContactsWrapper>>map = new HashMap<Long, ArrayList<ContactsWrapper>>();

        private ContactsAdapter adapter;

        private DataController controller;

        public ReadContacts(Context cntx, ListView contactList) {
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
            this.cntx = cntx;
            constants = new Constant();
            this.contactsList = contactList;

            controller = DataController.getInstance(); 
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPreExecute();
            if(!(controller.contactWrapper.size()>0))
                 constants.displayProgressDialog(cntx, "Loading Contacts...", "Please Wait");
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            if(!(controller.contactWrapper.size()>0))
            {
            try {
                String select = "((" + Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + " NOTNULL) AND ("
                        + Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER + "=1) AND ("
                        + Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + " != '' ))";

                Cursor c = cntx.getContentResolver().query(Contacts.CONTENT_URI, CONTACTS_SUMMARY_PROJECTION, select,
                        null, Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + " COLLATE LOCALIZED ASC");

                int colorcounter = 0;
                String[] colorcounter_array = { "#91A46B", "#8BB6B5", "#CAA973", "#8DA6C8","#D19B8D"};

                int color_string;
                for(int i=0;i<c.getCount();i++)
                {
    //              contactWrap.clear();
                    try {
                        contactId = 0;
                        String hasPhone = "";
                        display_name = "";
                        phoneNumber = "";

                        c.moveToPosition(i);

                        contactId =  c.getLong(0);
                        display_name = c.getString(1);
                        hasPhone = c.getString(7);

                        if (hasPhone.equalsIgnoreCase("1"))
                            hasPhone = "true";
                        else
                            hasPhone = "false" ;

                        if (Boolean.parseBoolean(hasPhone)) 
                        {
                            Cursor phones = cntx.getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null,ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID +" = "+ contactId,null, null);
                            while (phones.moveToNext()) 
                            {
                                int indexPhoneType = phones.getColumnIndexOrThrow(Phone.TYPE);
                                String phoneType =  phones.getString(indexPhoneType);

                                phoneNumber = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER)); 

                                String lookupKey = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.LOOKUP_KEY));

                                if (colorcounter < 5) 
                                {
                                    color_string =Color.parseColor(colorcounter_array[colorcounter]);
                                    colorcounter++;
                                } else {
                                    colorcounter = 0;
                                    color_string =Color.parseColor(colorcounter_array[colorcounter]);
                                    colorcounter++;
                                }
                                contactWrap.add(new ContactsWrapper(contactId, display_name, phoneNumber,lookupKey,false,color_string));
                            }
    //                      map.put(contactId, new ArrayList<ContactsWrapper>(contactWrap));
                            phones.close();
                        }
                    } catch (Exception e) {

                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }  
                }
                controller.contactWrapper = contactWrap;
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            constants.dismissDialog();

            adapter = new ContactsAdapter(cntx);
            contactsList.setAdapter(adapter);
        }

    }
```

and this is my contact wrapper class

```
package com.rightbackup.wrapper;

public class ContactsWrapper {

    private long contactId;
    private String displayName,displayNumber,lookUp;
    public boolean checked = true;
    int color_string;

    public ContactsWrapper(long contactId, String displayName, String displayNumber, String lookUp, boolean checked,int color_string) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        this.contactId = contactId;
        this.displayName = displayName;
        this.displayNumber = displayNumber;
        this.lookUp = lookUp;
        this.checked = checked;
        this.color_string =color_string;
    }

    public String getLookUp() {
        return lookUp;
    }

    public int getColor_string() {
        return color_string;
    }

    public boolean isChecked() {
        return checked;
    }

    public long getContactId() {
        return contactId;
    }

    public String getDisplayName() {
        return displayName;
    }

    public String getDisplayNumber() {
        return displayNumber;
    }

    public void setChecked(boolean checked) {
        this.checked = checked;
    }

}
```

Comment: hi...
can you tell me what you have done in   Constant and DataController class...?

Comment: ooo just forgot that dear

Comment: actually data-controller class is my cache class and constant is just like a common variable hold class so u dont want to make those classes

Comment: hi.. Bhanu Sharma ..Sorry for late reply..Suppose i have list of contact in my local db and if want to match it with device contact and display on that match content in list view .. then how can i achive that?.. please help me..

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41181/discussion-between-omsai-and-bhanu-sharma)

Comment: then just match dude like both are string so just check with contact name if u found match then add that contact in your display list and show that display list